# Кастомизация сохранения модели по клику на Save as new в админке Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком методе можно дописать дополнительный функционал для сохранения модели. В админке выставил

```
save_as = True
```

В модели есть уникальное поле slug. При сохранении конечно же выдает "Item with this Slug already exists." И при этом в методе save в модели ничего не происходит.

```
    def save_base(self, raw=False, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if Item.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists():
            self.sku = str(uuid.uuid4().fields[-1])[:9]
            self.slug = slugify('{0}-{1}'.format(self.name, self.sku))
        super(Item, self).save()
```

Comment: Принты в методе Save не отображаются.

Answer (score 0):

Если сохранение из админского интерфейса, то попробуйте `save_model()`

Comment: Делал, не помогает.

Comment: Использую джангу 1.11.10